# Java Compressing an Image using Arrays 2D to 1D?

Tags: java, arrays, image, compression, run-length-encoding

I am having trouble with an assignment of mine. I have a class which reads in PGM image files.
I need to create a few classes, the main one being a compression class. I need to compress the PGM (represented by 2D arrays) into a 1D array.

Here are the instructions:

```
public static short[] compress(short[][])
```

- Is passed a 2D array of shorts which represents an image.
- Returns the compressed image as a 1D array of shorts.
- **That method is my main concern**.

**Compression idea:**

- look for horizontal or vertical runs of like pixel values and record the number of times the 
  pixel value repeated itself.
- note by Spektre: this is called **RLE run length encoding** used by PCX for example

algorithm:

1.Compute the compressed image array using horizontal runs

2.Compute the compressed image array using vertical runs

3.Choose to compress the image uses the best technique for this particular image.

4.Set the Header of image

- Set the first and second values of your short [ ] result array to the width and height values.
- Set the third value in your short[ ] result array to 1 for horizontal or 2 for vertical compression.

5.Set the image body

- The rest of the short [ ] result array is filled with the RLE quantity and value

There are also a few other methods

- if anyone wants to help with them:

  ```
  public static void write(short[], String)
  ```
- Is passed a 1D array of shorts which represents the compressed image and a desired filename.
- Simply write the values to a text file with a .compressed extension added to the filename.

  ```
  public static short[] read(String)
  ```
- Is passed a compressed image filename.
- Simply reads the values and returns them in a 1D array of shorts.

  ```
  public static short[][] decompress(short[])
  ```
- Is passed a 1D array of shorts which represents a compressed image.
- Simply decompress the file so that we can display it on the screen
- using our showGrayImage( ) code that we already have.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: edited your question so check it out if I did not broke something. RLE is easy enough to do so it is a good choice for you ... there are many other compression algorithms with use of DCT,IDCT or variable bit-length but there are a bit complicated for beginners to code. Also I removed your PGM tag (which is not too helpful for you to make place for another one) and added new tag RLE (freaky that such basic therm as RLE tag was not yet created here so it will be invisible until someone approves it). you can google some PCX decoding/encoding sources for better starting point.

Comment: PS No one will code that for you ... start to code on your own and when you hit the wall with some problem edit the question by adding some source code (inside code block or just add 4,8,or 12 spaces before each code line) and or add concrete questions. (do not take this the wrong way it is just the way things work here on SO)

Comment: I'm just so lost tbh... *sigh* I wish I could get some realtime help.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/rle/info but I am not sure if you can see that page before peer approval.

Comment: first start to code compress() by doing no compression (skip steps 1,2,3) and decompress() without decompressing so you can call compress then decompress and see the output image somewhere. (both functions are just 2 nested for loops and data copy) when you done this only then try to start implementing compression. for starters try only lines compression (horizontal runs I think). when you done with it the rest will come to you ...